# Cant Texture Paint one part of the model

Tags: mesh, texturing, texture-painting

I made the mesh and now that I've finished it I wanted to paint it, but somehow it won't let me paint one of the hands, and I don't know what to do. Any solutions?[image]

EDIT: I realised that it might be because that hand was a copy of the other one,
 although I'm not really sure because the shoes are also a copy and I can paint them perfectly. (I got into this conclussion because I tried to copy the entire left arm and put it instead of the actual right arm and then all the arm, including the hand went white).

Comment: Select the hand in Edit Mode and press *Ctrl+N* to recalculate normals and then try to paint.

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: Ok I found out what was it, so I'll leave it here for anyone that has the same problem. It seems that if you want to copy an item, you have to go to the manu and duplicate it, you CAN'T do CTROL+C and CTRL+V (Maybe this is basic, but all the knowledege I've got are 3 YouTube videos xd). Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Mark the solution as an answer so that it doesn't appear as needing a solution still.

Comment: apply first the mirror before texture painting??